# Java web service in Silverlight

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-services

I am trying to consume a java web service that contains method `getSum(int a, int b)`. I have added the reference and written following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tournament.TournamentServiceClient c = new Tournament.TournamentServiceClient();
        c.getSumCompleted += new EventHandler<Tournament.getSumCompletedEventArgs>(completed);
        c.getSumAsync(45, 89);
    }

    private void completed(object sender, Tournament.getSumCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        label1.Content = args.Result;
    }
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get this error:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:8080/mkreal/TournamentServiceService'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

Where is the problem and how do I solve it?